# Is there a function to map every 10 char string to another unique 10 char string?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I need two functions:

```
enc("FE45LOABCD") -> "ABCDEFGHIJ"
dec("ABCDEFGHIJ") -> "FE45LOABCD"
```

The 10 char long input is always 10 chars long and the output of enc must be an unique 10 char long string too.
The input string must differ from the output string. The output string should look complete different to the input string.
The allowed letters that are in the ouput and input are `A` - `Z` and `0`-`9`

The dumb approach would be:

```
function enc(plaintext) {
  switch plaintext:
     case "AAAAAAAAA2":
        return "WGTHJURTZB";
     case "AAAAAAAAA3":
        return "TWRJK4QLJH";
     case "AAAAAAAAA4":
        return "WE7GHPLOYX";
     //and so on. In total 36^10 possibilities, that is obiously to much
}
```

Programming language is Javascript and i use NodeJS.
Is there a way how to solve this?

Comment: What is your aim? Have you ever looked at [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption)?

Comment: What sort of requirements do you want for that output? For example: if we simply output the original ten-character string, that would answer your current set of requirements.

Comment: Hey, the input string must differ from the output string. The output string should look complete different to the input string.

Comment: What is the range of each character?  Just digits and capital letters?  Or all 128/256 ASCII codes? Or UTF-8?  Unicode?  Etc., etc...?  There are tons of such one-to-one transform functions, but we'd need to know your actual base encoding before we could demonstrate and implementations.

Comment: Hey @RBarryYoung I updated the informations in my Question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13

Answer (score 2):

You just need a symmetric cipher -- any symmetric cipher can be adapted, though you want to make sure it supports the limited alphabet you want.  A good choice would be a vigenere cipher.  Something like [C code]:

```
bool vigenere(char *data, bool decode, const char *alphabet, const char *key) {
    size_t alpha_size = strlen(alphabet);
    size_t key_size = strlen(key);
    unsigned char code[key_size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < key_size; i++) {
        if (const char *p = strchr(alphabet, key[i])) {
            code[i] = p - alphabet;
            if (decode)
                code[i] = (alpha_size - code[i]) % alpha_size;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "key character %c not in the alphabet\n", key[i]);
            return false; } }
    for (size_t i = 0; data[i]; ++i) {
        if (const char *p = strchr(alphabet, data[i]))
            data[i] = alphabet[(p - alphabet + code[i % key_size]) % alpha_size]; }
    return true;
}
```

You would use this with `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"` as your alphabet (just a fixed string with all the characters that are legal, and NO REPEATS), and any string of those characters as the key (it need not be 10 chars long, but with 10 it would be pretty good for your requirements).

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is with a [Feistel network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher):

First, divide the string into two halves, and convert them to numbers `a` and `b`, where each number is in [0,36<sup>5</sup>].

Let LIMIT = 36<sup>5</sup>, and then:

```
repeat 3 times:
    a = (a + hash(b)%LIMIT ) % LIMIT
    b = (b + hash(a)%LIMIT ) % LIMIT
```

`hash()` can be any hash function.  When this is done you convert `a` and `b` back to strings and rejoin them.

To get back the original string, you need to undo that loop.  This is easy because each of the operations it performs is simple to invert:

```
repeat 3 times:
    b = (b + LIMIT - hash(a)%LIMIT ) % LIMIT
    a = (a + LIMIT - hash(b)%LIMIT ) % LIMIT
```

Note that the `+ LIMIT` part is there because we need to provide a positive value to the `%` operator.