# How to encode and decode sequential integer from DB to a pseudorandom Base36 6 character long string

Tags: algorithm, encoding, decoding

For a few days now I’m trying to find a solution for this problem but I haven’t had success yet.

I need to implement 2 functions:
One for encoding integer to string and one for decoding string to the original integer.
The encoded string needs to be 6 characters long, composed of uppercase letters and numbers (Base36) and needs to appear random. It doesn’t need to be highly secure, it just needs to appear random enough so someone who sees it couldn’t make a connection to the original integer at first sight.
Because I’m trying to encode IDs, every string should be unique for each given integer (no collisions).
I found and implemented a few algorithms that fulfill these requirements but there’s a problem: numbers that are next to each other are too similar. Basically they differ by one character. Even though it doesn’t have to be very secure, close numbers need to be as different as possible.
In reality, this algorithm will encode integers up to a 100k at most so higher values will most likely never be used, but for the solution to be great it would need to cover values up to few milions.

Example of what I need:
1 -> A39MNY
2 -> HDY19X
…
15 -> 2I8PZ9
etc.

I achieved this by using seeded Random objects, but the decoding part is the problem since I made the seed out of the inputted integer modified by a certain operations, so for the encoding to be achieved in one iteration, the original integer has to be known. Decoding is achieved by running encoding function until the number is found.

I’m willing to use some kind of encryption if these requirements are’t achievable by crafting some kind of simpler algorithm.

I’ve got really interested by this problem and I’m still actively digging for the solution. Any help that gets me a step closer to the solution is much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68792872/is-there-a-function-to-map-every-10-char-string-to-another-unique-10-char-string/68794040#68794040

Comment: If you use a lookup table / array / vector then the strings can be completely random, you just need to check for existing matches as you generate each new entry.  You can pre-generate as many entries as you need ahead of time.

Comment: Treat the ID as a 24-bit number. When encoding, first swap the least-significant byte with the most-significant byte, then base-36 encode. To decode, reverse the process. In general, any [reversible 1-to-1 mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911432/reversible-pseudo-random-sequence-generator) can be used to make the ID seem random before the base-36 encoding.

Comment: Looking at a [format preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) may be a solution, or at least suggest some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a large prime. Pick a random number in the range. Use Fermat's little theorem to scramble a large range.

You can encode `36^6 = 2176782336` different strings. Looking for a prime `p` a bit smaller than that, the best we can do is `2176782317`.

So now we just need a large number `n`.

```
import random
print(random.randomint(1, 2176782317))
```

This gave me `1173770130`.

Do a little arithmetic to find its inverse. For that we use the fact that if `p` is prime and `a` is relatively prime to p, then mod `p`, `1 = a^(p-1) = a * a^(p-2)` and so the multiplicative inverse is `a^(p-2)`.

```
def n_pow_m_mod_k (n, m, k):
    answer = 1
    power = n
    while 0 < m:
        if 1 == m % 2:
            answer = (answer * power) % k
            m -= 1
        m = m // 2
        power = (power * power) % k
    return answer

print(n_pow_m_mod_k(1173770130, 2176782317 - 2, 2176782317))
```

That gives `6232931` as the multiplicative inverse. Check it.

```
print((1173770130 * 6232931) % 2176782317)
```

It gives `1`, which is what we want.

Now let's turn these magic numbers into working code.

```
# Set up the character/number code.
alphabet = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMONPQRSTUVWXYZ'

chr_to_pos = {}
for i in range(len(alphabet)):
    chr_to_pos[alphabet[i]] = i


def id_to_code (n):
    m = (n * 1173770130) % 2176782317
    answer = ''
    for _ in range(6):
        answer += alphabet[m % 36]
        m = m // 36
    return answer

def code_to_id (code):
    m = 0
    for i in range(len(code)):
        m += chr_to_pos[code[i]] * 36**i
    return (m * 6232931) % 2176782317


for i in range(20):
    print(i, id_to_code(i), code_to_id(id_to_code(i)))
```

And there you have it. Easy to reverse codes with a not very easy to see pattern and a range of a couple of billion.

(DISCLAIMER: I took you at your word that you didn't need this to be secure. It is most definitely not secure.)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you.

Comment: @btilly how did you get the value 2176782315 when calling n_pow_m_mod_k()?

Comment: @TrentRenshaw I just added an explanation that follows from Fermat's little theorem.